# MySQL LIKE returning wrong results for special characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-like

The following PHP script with MySQL is basically working fine:

```
global $wpdb;

$keyword = $wpdb->_real_escape(strtolower($keyword));

$res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='product' AND post_status='publish' AND ((LOWER(post_title) LIKE '%{$keyword}%') OR (LOWER(post_content) LIKE '%{$keyword}%'))");
```

The results are correct for keywords like "gewinnen", "zeit" und "name". However If I use terms like "Rosé", "Günther", or "große" (everything with non ASCII characters) there are either no results or completely wrong results.

The WordPress default for wp_posts table regarding charset and collate are most probably:

```
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

What could be the reason and how may I solve this?

Comment: Seriously, use prepared statements. This kind of code shouldn't exist from a very very long time.

Comment: WordPress should have a prepare function use that instead.

Comment: :"However If I use terms like "Rosé", "Günther", or "große" (everything with non ASCII characters) "  how does the table look like `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts`  want to know the used database charset and collate.

Comment: First of all I should use `$wpdb->prepare` you are right anyway this is old code which I am maintaining.  Most probably COLLATE and charset are like: `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`